# Getting .tiff files from ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, export, layer-file

I'm new to ArcGIS.

I was given a map document that is composed of many .tiff files in .lyr format (it's only 4kb in size, so .tiff files are stored on some external server). Is it possible to export all of the .tiff files from it? [image: close up to to a .tiff file I need]
[image: each square represents .tiff file]

[image]

Layer Properties - Source

Comment: Your layer is a map service, so you are connecting to a server. What you can and cannot do it set by the administrator of the server. If you cannot see a data export option when you right click on the layer then I suspect they have disabled that option.